# use input parameter as attribute in search method python

Tags: python, attributes

I want to use the same search function for different attributes, depending on users choice. I'm trying to use the input parameters in the function **search** when searching for a specific animal.

I'm able to use x in the print but not in the loop..

For example, I want the loop to use attribute name (animalList[i].name) if x is set to name and age if x i set to age and so on. But when using animalList[i].x in the loop i get error "**'Animal' object has no attribute 'x'**". How can I use the attribute that x i set to?

```
def search(animalList, x):
    print("What " + x  +" are you searching for? ")
    searchFor = raw_input("Answer: ")
    i = 0
    for djur in animalList:
        if animalList[i].x == searchFor:
            returnVal = "In the park we have: ", animalList[i]
            break
        else:
            i += 1
            returnVal = "No match"
    return returnVal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the getattr function to do what you want:

```
getattr(animalList[i], x)
```

So it will be:

```
def search(animalList, x):
    print("What " + x  +" are you searching for? ")
    searchFor = raw_input("Answer: ")
    for animal in animalList: # this is the proper syntax for for loops
        if getattr(animal, x) == searchFor:
            returnVal = "In the park we have: ", animalList[i]
            break
        else:
            returnVal = "No match"
    return returnVal
```

This is under the assumption that animalList[i] is actually a function or something that actually have the x method.